# GitHub PR still fails test after another merged PR fixed the failing problem

Tags: git, github, pull-request

We have some pull requests people have made, which fail an automated analyze test/check (the failure was not related to any change the PR did, but I think a change in the analyze or formatting checks).

Another person has since fixed the issue with a new PR which has been merged which was causing the other PRs to fail the tests.

I was expecting if I "re-run all jobs", for the original PRs to now pass, but it's still failing with the same error (that the new PR has fixed). So I'm guessing it's still looking at the previous point before the new PR was merged.

What is the flow to get around this problem? (I could possibly just merge anyway and ignore the failed analyze test, but that doesn't feel quite right ?)

Comment: Some tools have an option to automatically re-create the temporary merge commit when either the *source* or *target* branch changes, and then re-run the tests. I'm not sure if GitHub offers that option in the context you're using it, but either rebasing that PR's branch onto the target (as described in [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70905804/184546)), or merging the target into it, will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The code in a PR is run "as is". If there was an "environmental" issue that was fixed, rerunning the jobs would indeed solve it.

In this case, another PR was merged in order to fix the problem. You should rebase your PR on top of the fix (probably on top of the `main` or `master` branch it was merged into) in order to be able to run the PR with the fixed tests.

Comment: Would a "rebase and merge" do this (not sure if that merges whatever, or would redo the tests) ?

Comment: @Ian that should work

Comment: @Ian if you're referring to the PR completion strategy of "rebase and merge", selecting that won't necessarily rebase your branch for you *before* you complete the PR. (I think...) If you want the test to pass *before* you complete the PR, you may need to rebase the branch yourself and force push it back out.